# fading JavaFX Popup allowing for extra content

Tags: java, popup, javafx

Here's a class to add as a popup , similar to JQuery modal dialog... And with the bindings you can add content and it will re size up, I'm not succeeding in re sizing down as the content size remains the same until the popup is closed.. Feel free to comment , improve, tailor and use

[image]

It is fixed to the center of the screen, but with a little bit of coding that can be movable.. (i just haven't bothered yet)

Regards D07114915

```
  package Utilities;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBuilder;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.RectangleBuilder;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class PopupMenu {

    private Group group;
    private Scene scene;
    private Node content;
    private Pane pane;
    private StackPane stackpane;
    private TilePane tile;
    private Rectangle outRectangle, inRectangle, borderRectangle;
    private Button closeBtn;
    private final Double MIN_HEIGHT = 60.0, MIN_WIDTH = 80.0;
    private Double height, width;
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty sdpHeightInRect = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty sdpWidthInRect = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty sdpHeightBorderRect = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty sdpWidthBorderRect = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty tileX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty tileY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty closeBtnX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty closeBtnY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private final int BORDER_SIZE = 3;
    private final int CONTENT_PADDING = 20;

    public PopupMenu(final Scene scene, final Node content) {
        this.content = content;
        this.content.setVisible(true);
        this.content.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {

            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                calculateWidthAndHeight();
            }
        });

        this.group = (Group) scene.getRoot();
        this.scene = scene;

        outRectangle = RectangleBuilder.create().width(scene.getWidth() - 2).height(scene.getHeight() - 2).opacity(0.2).fill(Color.BLACK).onMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                event.consume();
                closeMenu();
            }
        }).build();

        inRectangle = RectangleBuilder.create().width(sdpHeightInRect.get()).height(sdpWidthInRect.get()).fill(Color.WHITESMOKE).arcHeight(10).arcWidth(10).opacity(0.9).build();
        inRectangle.heightProperty().bindBidirectional(sdpHeightInRect);
        inRectangle.widthProperty().bindBidirectional(sdpWidthInRect);

        borderRectangle = RectangleBuilder.create().width(sdpWidthBorderRect.get()).height(sdpHeightBorderRect.get()).arcHeight(10).arcWidth(10).opacity(0.9).build();
        borderRectangle.heightProperty().bindBidirectional(sdpHeightBorderRect);
        borderRectangle.widthProperty().bindBidirectional(sdpWidthBorderRect);

        tile = TilePaneBuilder.create().orientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL).tileAlignment(Pos.CENTER).managed(false).children(this.content).build();
        tile.layoutXProperty().bindBidirectional(tileX);
        tile.layoutYProperty().bindBidirectional(tileY);

        stackpane = StackPaneBuilder.create().alignment(Pos.CENTER).children(outRectangle, borderRectangle, inRectangle, tile).build();

        closeBtn = ButtonBuilder.create().text("[X]").cancelButton(true).visible(true).onAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                closeMenu();
            }
        }).build();

        closeBtn.layoutXProperty().bindBidirectional(closeBtnX);
        closeBtn.layoutYProperty().bindBidirectional(closeBtnY);

        pane = PaneBuilder.create().children(stackpane, closeBtn).build();

        //This is needed to fire to set everything first time around. Otherwise the display is not centered
        // when the popup is shown on subsequent ocasions without the content being altered
                calculateWidthAndHeight();
    }

    public void openMenu() {
        group.getChildren().addAll(pane);

        FadeTransition fadein = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(800), pane);
        fadein.setFromValue(0.0);
        fadein.setToValue(1.0);
        fadein.play();
    }

    public void closeMenu() {
        FadeTransition fadeout = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(700), pane);
        fadeout.setFromValue(1.0);
        fadeout.setToValue(0.0);
        fadeout.play();
        fadeout.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                group.getChildren().removeAll(pane);
            }
        });
    }

    private void calculateWidthAndHeight() {
        Bounds boundsInLocal = this.content.getBoundsInLocal();
        height = (boundsInLocal.getHeight() < MIN_HEIGHT) ? MIN_HEIGHT : boundsInLocal.getHeight();
        width = (boundsInLocal.getWidth() < MIN_WIDTH) ? MIN_WIDTH : boundsInLocal.getWidth();

        sdpHeightInRect.set(height + CONTENT_PADDING);
        sdpWidthInRect.set(width + CONTENT_PADDING);

        sdpHeightBorderRect.set(sdpHeightInRect.get() + BORDER_SIZE);
        sdpWidthBorderRect.set(sdpWidthInRect.get() + BORDER_SIZE);

        tileX.set(scene.getWidth() / 2 - width / 2);
        tileY.set(scene.getHeight() / 2 - height / 2);

        closeBtnX.set((scene.getWidth() / 2) - 18);
        closeBtnY.set((scene.getHeight() - (scene.getHeight() - borderRectangle.getHeight()) / 2) - (((borderRectangle.getHeight() - inRectangle.getHeight()) * 2)) - 5);
        System.err.println("H:" + height + ", W:" + width);
    }
}// end of class
```

To fire this in your main class you would do something like this

```
Scene scene;

VBox popupBOX = VBoxBuilder.create().children(new Label("MY CONTENT").visible(false).build();

        final Button firePopup = ButtonBuilder.create().text("FIRE POPUP").build()).onAction(new EventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            new PopupMenu(scene, popupBOX).openMenu();
        }
    }).build()
```

And note the popupBOX node should be added already to the current working scene(This allows the calculation of layout, width etc), it is just hidden, but is set visible in the PopupMenu class....